# Are there issues with mixing percentages and pixels in the same rule?

Tags: css, pixel, percentage

Just simply wondering if using percentages and pixels in the same css rule is bad practice, and if so what the bi-product of this would be.

Examples:

```
.left {
    width:59%;
    height:500px;
    float:left;
    margin-right:5.1%;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.70);
    background-repeat:repeat;
    margin-top:5%;
}
.pic {
    width:90%;
    height:90%;
    margin:25px auto 0 auto;
    background:url('img/picOne.png');
    background-position:center center;
    -webkit-background-size:cover;
    -moz-background-size:cover;
    -o-background-size:cover;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

Comment: "Bad practice" is an opinion; try to write questions in a way in which they can be *objectively* answered.

Comment: No; there can be a lot of good reasons to combine different types of units on one element.

Comment: It's an opinion if doing so causes certain behaviors that are not intended to set rules? @user2864740

Comment: @user2684452 *"try to write questions in way in which.."*; by *asking* if something is a "bad practice" you introduce and request opinion. Simply don't.

Answer (score 0):

I have never encountered that as a best practice. Function trumps and code style (potential?) concerns, as you might need a percentage width and a pixel height, for example. For instance, if you had a three column layout, and needed a fixed height, you might do something like,

```
.elements {
  width: 33%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

I would say use the same measurements if the two units make no functional difference, but otherwise use what is needed.